# Showing custom InfoWindow for Android Maps Utility Library for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I'm using the library [Google Maps Utility for Android](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) which allows to create clustering int he maps and I need to show a custom `InfoWindow` but I can't find any method to do this.
In order to show the info window, I have the following class, and in the method `onClusterItemRendered` is where I have access to the info of the marker:

```
class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MarkerItem> {

    public MyClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
            ClusterManager<MarkerItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MarkerItem item,
            MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
        markerOptions.title(String.valueOf(item.getMarkerId()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(MarkerItem clusterItem,
            Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
    }
}
```

Is there anybody who has used the library and knows how to show a custom `InfoWindow` such as the way it was used in the Google Maps? Like:

```
getMap().setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. `ClusterManager` maintains two `MarkerManager.Collections`:

- one for cluster markers, and
- one for individual item markers

You can set a custom `InfoWindowAdapter` for each of these kinds of markers independently.

---

### Implementation

First, install your ClusterManager's MarkerManager as the map's InfoWindowAdapter:

```
ClusterManager<MarkerItem> clusterMgr = new ClusterManager<MarkerItem>(context, map);
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(clusterMgr.getMarkerManager());
```

Next, install your custom `InfoWindowAdapter` as the adapter for one or both of the marker collections:

```
clusterMgr.getClusterMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(new MyCustomAdapterForClusters());
clusterMgr.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(new MyCustomAdapterForItems());
```

The final piece is mapping the raw `Marker` object that you'll receive in your custom InfoWindowAdapter's callback to the `ClusterItem` object(s) that you added to the map in the first place. This can be achieved using the onClusterClick and onClusterItemClick listeners, as follows:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterMgr);
clusterMgr.setOnClusterClickListener(new OnClusterClickListener<MarkerItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MarkerItem> cluster) {
        clickedCluster = cluster; // remember for use later in the Adapter
        return false;
    }
});
clusterMgr.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new OnClusterItemClickListener<MarkerItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MarkerItem item) {
        clickedClusterItem = item;
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

Now you have everything you need to assemble your custom InfoWindow content in your respective Adapters! For example:

```
class MyCustomAdapterForClusters implements InfoWindowAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        if (clickedCluster != null) {
            for (MarkerItem item : clickedCluster.getItems()) {
                // Extract data from each item in the cluster as needed
            }
        }
        // build your custom view
        // ...
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good job! I just want to warn people, i haven't noticed a piece of code: `map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterMgr);` and the callback was never hit.
It's obviously needed to do as commented in source code:

`/*Sets a callback that's invoked when an individual ClusterItem is tapped. Note: For thislistener to function, the ClusterManager must be added as a click listener to the map.
 */
    public void setOnClusterItemClickListener(OnClusterItemClickListener<T> listener) {
        mOnClusterItemClickListener = listener;
        mRenderer.setOnClusterItemClickListener(listener);
    }`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? I do call map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterMgr) in my sample code above, immediately before setting the onCluster and onClusterItem click listeners.

Comment: All is ok, it was just my mistake, so I wanted to highlight this point

Comment: Was struggling on the similar issue until stumbled upon your comment. It opened my eyes :) Thanks

Comment: It looks like there's a far better way to do this now, from 0.3.2 forward, https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/48

Comment: setOnInfoWindowAdapter showing unresolved reference

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have your class starting like this:

```
private class MarkerItemClusterRenderer extends
        DefaultClusterRenderer<MarkerItem> {
    public MarkerItemClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
            ClusterManager<MarkerItem> clusterManager) {
    ...
```

So in that parameter `map` of the type `GoogleMap` is where you have to specify your `setInfoWindowAdapter`.

Comment: is this elaboration of the first answer or?