# Android Custom InfoWindow using marker clusters

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm clustering markers using the google maps api. Since I want a custom icon as a marker, I've created a  custom renderer (that extends `DefaultClusterRenderer`). On `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` I'm setting the desired icon.

The problem is that I now want to create a custom `infowindow`. If I do:

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {



        }
    });
```

In the `getInfoContents` I can customize the infowindow. The problem is that the passed params are of type `Marker`. Because I'm using clustering I'm using a custom marker (`MyMarker`) that as info in it.
I can't cast `Marker` to `MyMarker` nor can change the params to `MyMarker`. I wan't to do this to extract the info.

How can I still maintain the clustering (here I can access `MyMarker` info) but creating a custom infowindow?

```
public MarkerRenderer() {
        super(getActivity(), mGoogleMap, mClusterManager);         

    }



    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyMarker myMarker, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(myMarker.getMarkerImage())).title(
                "This is my custom marker with the default infoWindo");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyMarker> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions);
        markerOptions.title("cluster size " + cluster.getSize());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21964693/295028) suggests storing a reference to your cluster or marker in your click listener.

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterMgr);
clusterMgr.setOnClusterClickListener(new OnClusterClickListener<MarkerItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MarkerItem> cluster) {
        clickedCluster = cluster; // remember for use later in the Adapter
        return false;
    }
});
clusterMgr.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new OnClusterItemClickListener<MarkerItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MarkerItem item) {
        clickedClusterItem = item;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then you can use that reference in your adapter.

```
class MyCustomAdapterForClusters implements InfoWindowAdapter {
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    if (clickedCluster != null) {
        for (MarkerItem item : clickedCluster.getItems()) {
            // Extract data from each item in the cluster as needed
        }
    }
    // build your custom view
    // ...
    return view;
}
}
```

The sample code refers to an InfoWindowAdapter, but it should work as well for a MarkerRenderer; you could pass your custom marker as a parameter to the constructor.