# Update marker position on database update Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a set of latitudes and longitudes saved in MySQL database. I plot them on my map using:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    double lat = json_data.getDouble("lat");
                    double lng= json_data.getDouble("long");
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
```

(I use Async Task to fetch the location and  have kept a Timer to keep calling that Task)
These locations correspond to particular vehicles, hence I plan to add that using this link

[Showing custom InfoWindow for Android Maps Utility Library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885225/showing-custom-infowindow-for-android-maps-utility-library-for-android).

My question is that once the location of a particular entry is updated in the database I need to find that marker and move/animate the marker to new new positon.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your markers you need to store them somewhere, like an array or list. You need to have each marker identified in a way that associates a marker with the location. Markers have a [ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getId()) property that is unique across the map, so you can try using that. Alternatively, you can use the [Title](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getTitle()) or content in the InfoWindow to differentiate the markers. You can also try using the [position](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getPosition()) the marker assuming you can retrieve the "old" position before you update it. With whatever method you use, once you get a match, you can then update the marker position with [setPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setPosition(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)).

There are also some [third party libraries](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) available with which you can retrieve markers with.

Comment: clusterManager automatically creates a list. Had to use a Handler to create a new thread that can alter the UI of the app, but finally code worked! Thanks alot.