# google maps android api utility library - custom cluster icon

Tags: java, google-api

I'm using Google Maps Android API Utility Library in order to show several markers in a map in a clustered way. I can't find a way to change default CLUSTER ICON, not marker icon (this is simple).

Answer (score 0):

I found, of course on http://stackoverflow.com

[Android maps utils cluster icon color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967961/android-maps-utils-cluster-icon-color)