# How to change cluster image according to the number of marker it included, in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

Following image contains different cluster styles according to the size of it. This is exactly what I'm trying to do from Android. I'm using `ClusterManager` from `android-maps-util`.

[image]

Here's the javascript code that server guy used. 
If possible, I need the same idea to do so.

```
gmap.mc.styles_ = [{ url: markersBaseLocation + 'm1.png', height: 53, width: 53 }, { url: markersBaseLocation + 'm2.png', height: 56, width: 57 }, { url: markersBaseLocation + 'm3.png', height: 66, width: 66 }, { url: markersBaseLocation + 'm4.png', height: 78, width: 78 }, { url: markersBaseLocation + 'm5.png', height: 90, width: 90 }];
```

Comment: You have to subclass DefaultClusterRenderer, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967961/android-maps-utils-cluster-icon-color

Comment: I'm trying that one.. thank you so much. @DanielNugent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by providing your own custom Renderer.

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem>(mContext, googleMap, mClusterManager) {
        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            // use cluster.getSize() to get the number of markers inside the cluster.
        }
```

The demo code for this can be found in https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils.git. Look inside "CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java"

Comment: yap..., that's how i did.