# How to change the color of markers in cluster?

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer, markers

I searched and found out that it is possible to change color of only the cluster icon, the markers take only the default color
please help...thanks is advance

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
private final LatLng mPosition;
private final String mTitle;
private final String mSnippet;

public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

public MyItem(double lat, double lng, String title, String snippet) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mTitle = title;
    mSnippet = snippet;
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}

@Override
public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

@Override
public String getSnippet() {
    return mSnippet;
} }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967961/android-maps-utils-cluster-icon-color

Answer (score 0):

We can Override getColor in CustomClusterRenderer.

```
public class CustomClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<CustomClusterItem> {

@Override
    protected int getColor(int clusterSize) {
        return Color.parseColor("#567238");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `textColor` which sets the color of the label text shown on the cluster icon. You can see the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering).